# change values for each object with a button

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have an array map with objects in JavaScript, the map consists of a title and list items, for list item Amount I use add and minus button, to change values in Amount, how can I change the values in the HTML but for each one object only?

```js
    const outputHtml = matches => {
        if (matches.length > 0) {
            const lookUpItem = matches.map(match => `
            <div class="foodInfo">
                    <h4 id="title">${match.foodDesc}</h4>
                    <small><span class="foodDetails">
                        <li>Protein: ${match.Protein} g</li>
                        <li>Calories: ${match.Calories} cals</li>
                        <li>Total Fat: ${match.Fat} g</li>
                        <li><button onclick="minus()" id="minus">-</button>
                            <span id="amount">Amount: <span id="amountNumber">${match.amount1}</span> / ${match.msreDesc1} </span>
                            <button onclick="add()" id="add">+</button> </li>
                        <button onclick="submit()" id="submit">Add to Diary</button>
                    </span></small>
            </div>
            `
    ).join('');
            itemList.innerHTML = lookUpItem;
        }
    }

function add() {
    {
      const amountNum = document.getElementById('amountNumber');
      console.log(amountNum.innerText)
  }
}
```

The JSON file is fetched with API URL, here is a snippet of .json file

```js
 [
    {
       "foodDesc": "French baguette by Panera bread",
       "foodId": 738220,
       "Calories": "263,1578947",
       "Fat": "1,75438596",
       "amount1": "1",
       "Protein": "8,77192982",
       },
     {
       "foodDesc": "Broccoli cheddar by Panera bread",
       "foodId": 738375,
       "Calories": "300",
       "Fat": "19",
       "amount1": "1,5",
       "Protein": "12",
       },
     {
       "foodDesc": "Whole grain baguette by Panera bread",
       "foodId": 738240,
       "Calories": "245,6140351",
       "Fat": "1,75438596",
       "amount1": "1",
       "Protein": "10,52631579"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Use unique IDs for starters. You can pass the id into the function rather than having the function look for it.  add('amountNumber_x')

Comment: Unique ID's as in the foodID's in json file?

Comment: No, the ID on the element you're trying to adjust. Also your plus/minus buttons.  Glancing at your code, each block of food elements use the same IDs as all the others displayed.

Comment: So for each block i should have an different an element ID? Can i ask what same IDs u mean?

Comment: Every add and minus button you display share the same ID.  Every span element containing the amount share the same ID.  ID has to be unique!

Comment: @Leny Le The, please see my update the answer.

Comment: JSON is a text format, and you're dealing with objects and arrays, so I removed the stuff about JSON. Note that clicking on Run code snippet on your first snippet does nothing, so it's not really helping your question. If you were to include the HTML in the snippet, and show how `outputHtml` is called, that would go a long way toward making a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map function also has an index value. Use that to create unique ID values.

```
    const outputHtml = matches => {
        if (matches.length > 0) {
            const lookUpItem = matches.map((match, index) => `
            <div class="foodInfo">
                    <h4 id="title">${match.foodDesc}</h4>
                    <small><span class="foodDetails">
                        <li>Protein: ${match.Protein} g</li>
                        <li>Calories: ${match.Calories} cals</li>
                        <li>Total Fat: ${match.Fat} g</li>
                        <li><button onclick="minus('amountNumber_${index}')" id="minus_${index}">-</button>
                            <span id="amount">Amount: <span id="amountNumber_${index}">${match.amount1}</span> / ${match.msreDesc1} </span>
                            <button onclick="add('amountNumber_${index}')" id="add_${index}">+</button> </li>
                        <button onclick="submit()" id="submit">Add to Diary</button>
                    </span></small>
            </div>
            `
    ).join('');
            itemList.innerHTML = lookUpItem;
        }
    }
    
    

function add(el) {

    amountNum = parseInt(document.getElementById(el)) + 1;

    document.getElementById(el).innerText = amountNum;

    console.log(amountNum.innerText)
}
```

Comment: the $index is searched i the json file? The amount is NaN when i click the button

Comment: You're loading data onto the page from a json, right? You don't manipulate data directly in a json file, you'd have to write that back out after updating the values read into memory.

Comment: Yes, just loading and it changes in the HTML. You are right, but how can i change the numbers in the html then?

Comment: Look at my code example, it does that in the add function

Answer (score 0):

First make each span have a unique ID:

```
<span id="amountNumber_' + ${match.foodId} + '">
```

Pass the that ID to the `add` function:

```
<button onclick="add(amountNumber_' + ${match.foodId} + ')" id="add">+</button>
```

And add the parameter to the `add` function:

```
function add(id) {
{
    const amountNum = document.getElementById(id);
    console.log(amountNum.innerText)
}
```

Note: You may have to escape `${match.foodId}` in the code segments above as I didn't had the chance to test it.

**EDIT:**
If you want to change every macro nutrient you'll to have a `span` for each one. Using protein as an example:

```
<li>Protein: <span id="protein_' + ${match.foodId} +'>${match.Protein}</span> g</li>
```

Pass just the id as parameter:

```
<button onclick="add(' + ${match.foodId} + ')" id="add">+</button>
```

And change your `add` function to something like (might require tweaking):

```
function add(id) {
{
    const amountNum = document.getElementById("amountNumber_' + ${match.foodId} +'");
    console.log(amountNum.innerText)

    var span = document.getElementById("protein_' + ${match.foodId} +'");
    span.innerText += parseFloat(span.innerText) 
}
```

Comment: For each span, so that means also for the one with class "FoodDetails"? Also how do I increase the amount? What to put into the function, if i want to click on the button it should change the amount but also increase the number of other item list like fat/protein?

Comment: No, for each `span` referring to `amountNumber`. That second part is an entirely different question but I'll edit my answer.